# selection sort in javascript via Khan Academy

Tags: javascript, algorithm

I am not sure what Im doing wrong in my code, but it sorts the numbers correctly, but also leaves this output:

```
Array after sorting: ,,,,,,,7,,9,,11,,,,,,,,,,,22,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,42,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,88,,,,,,,,,,,99
```

Please help me troubleshoot my code!

```
var swap = function(array, firstIndex, secondIndex) {
        var temp = array[firstIndex];
        array[firstIndex] = array[secondIndex];
        array[secondIndex] = temp;
    };

var indexOfMinimum = function(array, startIndex) {

    var minValue = array[startIndex];
    var minIndex = startIndex;

    for(var i = minIndex + 1; i < array.length; i++) {
        if(array[i] < minValue) {
            minIndex = i;
            minValue = array[i];
        }
    } 
    return minIndex;
}; 

var selectionSort = function(array) {
    var length = array.length;
    for(var i = 0; i < length; i++){
        var min = indexOfMinimum(array,array[i]);
        swap(array, i, min);
    }
};

var array = [22, 11, 99, 88, 9, 7, 42];
selectionSort(array);
println("Array after sorting: " + array);

Program.assertEqual(array, [7, 9, 11, 22, 42, 88, 99]);
```

Comment: nevermind I figured out my error. For indexOfMinimum I need to pass in i not array[i]

Answer (score 1):

You don't want the value at index `i`, you just want `i` itself.

```
var min = indexOfMinimum(array, array[i]);
```

should be

```
var min = indexOfMinimum(array, i);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var selectionSort = function(array) {

    var length = array.length;

    for(var i = 0; i < length; i++){
        var min = indexOfMinimum(array,i);
        swap(array, i, min);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var selectionSort = function(array) {
var minIdx;
for(var i = 0; i < array.length - 1; i++){
    minIdx = indexOfMinimum(array, i);
    swap(array, minIdx, i);
}
return array;
```

Answer (score 0):

the full solution for the 2 phases:

```
var swap = function(array, firstIndex, secondIndex) {
var temp = array[firstIndex];
array[firstIndex] = array[secondIndex];
array[secondIndex] = temp;
};

var indexOfMinimum = function(array, startIndex) {

var minValue = array[startIndex];
var minIndex = startIndex;

for(var i = minIndex + 1; i < array.length; i++) {
    if(array[i] < minValue) {
        minIndex = i;
        minValue = array[i];
    }
} 
return minIndex;
}; 

var selectionSort = function(array) {
var new_index;
for(var index = 0; index < array.length ; index++) {
    new_index = indexOfMinimum(array, index);
    swap(array,new_index ,index );
}
};

var array = [22, 11, 99, 88, 9, 7, 42];
var array2 = [22, 15, 99, 88, 9, 7, 42];
selectionSort(array);
selectionSort(array2);
println("Array after sorting:  " + array);

Program.assertEqual(array, [7, 9, 11, 22, 42, 88, 99]);
Program.assertEqual(array2, [7, 9, 15, 22, 42, 88, 99]);
```